# GStreamer API in OpenCV: autovideosink vs appsink

Tags: opencv, c++14, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer, video-capture

The following Gstreamer Receiver command works fine when I run it on the terminal.

> gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5004 !
> 'application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264' ! rtpjitterbuffer
> mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert !
> autovideosink

I need to do capture these frames and do some processing using OpenCV's Gstreamer API. I used the exact pipeline in my C++ code but the VideoCapture is failing to start. The code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", CAP_GSTREAMER);
    
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr <<"VideoCapture not opened"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    while (true) {

        Mat frame;

        cap.read(frame);

        imshow("receiver", frame);

        //  Process the frame.

        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile and run I receive:

> (Receiver_Teal:2292): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state:
> assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
>
> VideoCapture not opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `autovideosink` at the end with `appsink`

```
VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink", CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Can you add your answer why it works? I don't understand why the autovideosink works on the command line prompt but not in C++ code.

Comment: When you give OpenCV a custom pipeline, the library needs to be able to pull the frames out of that pipeline and provide them to you. The appsink element makes these frames available to OpenCV, whereas autovideosink simply displays the frames in a window on your screen. Every custom pipeline you give OpenCV needs to have an appsink element for that reason.